# Procedure created with compilation error PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure numOfSupplier(X IN NUMBER)IS

OUTPUT VARCHAR2(300);

BEGIN
SELECT R_NAME, N_NAME, COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
into output
FROM SUPPLIER join NATION on S_NATIONKEY = N_NATIONKEY
join REGION on N_REGIONKEY = R_REGIONKEY
GROUP BY R_NAME, N_NAME
HAVING COUNT (S_NATIONKEY) > X;

dbms_output.put_line( OUTPUT );

END numOfSupplier; 
/
```

I am trying to create a procedure where I specify a number e.g 130 and it will list the name of the region, the name of the nation, and the number of suppliers in that nation that is more than 130. My expected output is e.g.

R_NAME N_Name COUNT(S_NATIONEKY)

---

ASIA INDONESIA 131

ASIA CHINA  132

however when I run my script it returns PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values. I am unsure why is it like that. I have run my select statement separately and it was working fine however when I made it into a procedure it is not working. Can anyone out there help me identify where is the problem please.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to concatenate to a string, so you get an array of concatenated string of R_NAME, N_NAME and COUNT.

Modified procedure is below,

```
create or replace procedure numOfSupplier(X IN NUMBER)IS

TYPE type_supplier  is table of varchar2(200) Index by binary_integer;
tab_supplier type_supplier;
counter NUMBER(10):=0;

BEGIN

--Cursor to loop through the records returned
for cur_suppliers in
(SELECT R_NAME||' '|| N_NAME||' '|| COUNT(S_NATIONKEY) output
FROM SUPPLIER join NATION on S_NATIONKEY = N_NATIONKEY
join REGION on N_REGIONKEY = R_REGIONKEY
GROUP BY R_NAME, N_NAME
HAVING COUNT (S_NATIONKEY) > X)


LOOP
counter := counter + 1;
--Load the data to array indexed by integer 
 tab_supplier(counter) := cur_suppliers.output;
END LOOP;

--Loop through the array and print the array 
FOR i IN tab_supplier.FIRST..tab_supplier.LAST LOOP
Dbms_output.put_line ('Values are : ' ||tab_supplier(i));

END LOOP;

END numOfSupplier; 
/
```

Running the procedure in anonymous block should return,

```
EXEC numOfSupplier;

Values are : ASIA INDONESIA 131
Values are : EUROPE UK 121
Values are : ASIA INDIA 111
```

Comment: Hi sir, I have tried you method and the procedure is working fine now. However when I run my procedure it returns 3 errors:                                                                                     ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "CSCI235.NUMBEROFSUPPLIER", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: That's the way it should work. I believe the query returns more than one rows for the X value you have passed.Variable "output" is varchar and can only take a single string and not array of string. Group by R_NAME,N_NAME would be returning multiple rows which cannot be handled by a varchar datatype. You need a array to handle it. Let me know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I am actually looking at returning multiple row. I am new to sqlplus so im not too sure how I can store my strings into an array to handle it. I am trying to print it out in columns as well? so my initial assumption was to put the output as a string I can concatenate it. Appreciate your help sir

Comment: Please refer updated code. Now this returns a VARCHAR2 array indexed by binary integer . You can also define multi-dimensional array with more that one columns,that allows to store each of 3 columns seperately in the array. For more information refer http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/42139/0/

Comment: Hi sir thank you so much for the updated code,  but the main goal of this procedure is so I can give it a number parameter e.g 130 so I can print out rows of records with the region name, nation name and the number of supplier count of more than 130?

Comment: Apologies, looks like i had a copy paste error, i had to test on objects that i have. Please check the updated code now and feedback.

Comment: Alright sir! im sorry another quick question. how do I run the procedure in an anonymous block?

Comment: You can run using "EXEC numOfSupplier;"  or enclose the stored procedure within begin and end , like  begin numOfSupplier; end; If you get the desired output feedback and mark the Answer.